# Jquery Datepicker works but verification goes away

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I had an assignment and I had a issue I could not resolve. I added the jqueryui datepicker plugin and all of my form verification goes away.

Below is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-ca" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle3.css">
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/vendor/js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/vendor/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/vendor/js/additional-methods.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
      maxDate: -1,
      showButtonPanel: true


    });
  });
  </script>    

<script>
$(function() {

   $( "#inputform" ).validate({rules: {
                   fname: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 2,
                           maxlength: 20,
                           alphanumeric: true,


    },
                   lname: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 2,
                           maxlength: 20,
                           alphanumeric: true,
    },
                   street: { 
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,
                           street: true,

 },
                    city: { 
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,

 },
                    zip: { 
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,
                           maxlength: 5,
                           digits: true,
                           zip: true
 },                  tel: { 
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 10,
                           tele: true,


 },                  email: { 
                           required: true,
                           email: true

 }

           },
           messages: {


           }
   });

   $.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric",
           function(value, element) {
                   return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
           },
   "Sorry, no special characters allowed"
   );



});
   $.validator.addMethod('zip', function (value) { 
    return /^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))$/.test(value); 
}, 'Please enter a valid US zip code.');

    $.validator.addMethod('street', function (value) { 
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] ?([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]|[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] )*[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]$/.test(value); 
}, 'Please enter a valid street address.');

    $.validator.addMethod('city', function (value) { 
    return /^[a-zA-z] ?([a-zA-z]|[a-zA-z] )*[a-zA-z]$/.test(value); 
}, 'Please enter a valid City.');

    $.validator.addMethod('tele', function (value) { 
    return /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/.test(value); 
}, 'Please enter a valid Telephone number.');





</script>


            <title>Assignment 3 Input form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.jkozla.com/default.htm"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Assignments</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment1.htm><span>Assignment 1</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment2.htm><span>Assignment 2</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment3.html><span>Assignment 3</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment4.htm><span>Assignment 4</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment5.htm><span>Assignment 5</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment6.htm><span>Assignment 6</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment7.htm><span>Assignment 7</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment8.htm><span>Assignment 8</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment9.htm><span>Assignment 9</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment10.htm><span>Assignment 10</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment11.htm><span>Assignment 11</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='active has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Classes</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href="https://cop4813eaglin.pbworks.com/w/page/34415594/FrontPage"><span>COP4813</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href="https://cas.fsu.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fcampus.fsu.edu%2Fwebapps%2Fbb-auth-provider-cas-bb_bb60%2Fexecute%2FcasLogin%3Fcmd%3Dlogin%26authProviderId%3D_105_1%26redirectUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcampus.fsu.edu%252Fwebapps%252Fportal%252Fframeset.jsp%26sessionIdForLogout%3DEB7D8A9EDEE7CA79B83CA34E8C9FA206"><span>MAD2104</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='active has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Project</span></a>

                    <li class='last'><a href="mailto:jmk13c@my.fsu.edu"><span>Contact</span></a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

<h1>COP 4813 Form Validation</h1>

    <form id="inputform" method="get"  onsubmit="javascript:alert('I do also submit');">
                  <p>
                      <label for="fname">First Name:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="fname" class="fname" type="text"  size="15" />
        </p>
         <p>
             <label for="lname">Last Name:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="lname" class="required" type="text"  size="15" />
        </p>
         <p>
             <label for="street">Street Address:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="street" class="required" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" size="20" />
        </p>
         <p>
             <label for="city">City:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="city" class="required" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" size="15" />
        </p>
                 <p>
                       <label for="state">State:&nbsp;</label>
                  <select name="state" size="1">
                      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                      <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                      <option value="CA">California</option>
                      <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                      <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                      <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                      <option value="DC">Dist of Columbia</option>
                      <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                      <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                      <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                      <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                      <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                      <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                      <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                      <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                      <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                      <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                      <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                      <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                      <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                      <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                      <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                      <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                      <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                      <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                      <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                      <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                      <option value="NY">New York</option>
                      <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                      <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                      <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                      <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                      <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                      <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                      <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                      <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                      <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                      <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                      <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                      <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                      <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                      <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                      <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                      <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                       </select>

                     <p>
                         <label for="zip">Zipcode:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="zip" class="required" type="text" size="8" />
                     </p>

                     <p>
                         <label for="tel">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="tel" class="required" type="tel" data-mask="(000) 000-0000" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" size="10" />
                     </p>

                     <p>
                         <label for="dob">DOB:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="dob" type="date" class="required" id="datepicker" size="15" />
                     </p>
                     <p>
                         <label for="email">Email:&nbsp;</label>
                  <input name="email" type="email" class="required"  size="15" />
                     </p>
                     <p>
                         Message:</p>
                     <p><textarea name="comment" required rows="4" cols="50"> 
</textarea> 
                     </p>

                  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

            </form>            

    </body>

</html>
```

When i remove the code below, my verification return. Any ideas would be great!

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
      maxDate: -1,
      showButtonPanel: true


    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Were there any error messages in the browser console ?

Comment: i take it back, TypeError: $.validator is undefined Assignment3.html:97:3
TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function Assignment3.html:36:0

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jkozla01/z0pk7pk4/  here is the link, datepicker works and nothing else. Play around help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have jQuery.js included 3 times.

Each time you load it it will overwrite the previous jQuery object.
Any plugins that were bound to the previous object will also be lost.

You should have been seeing an error that `validate` is not a function as a result of this.

Also note you are loading `jquery.validate` multiple times.

Only load jQuery.js once....before all plugins and dependent code

Comment: When i removed all and just had the lastest jquery nothiing works

Comment: should work fine if jQuery UI version is compatible and you load jQuery.js before all other dependent code. What errors are thrown?

Comment: from the jQuery UI  docs. Generally better not to use `latest` and use known version to be honest

Comment: any idea what to use then

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the idea that the issue is with the $ conflict due to multiple jQuery library imports.

Notice the two imports for the jQuery library after loading the minified version.

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`
and
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>`

Removing them should help.

Additionally, it would be recommended to add `$.noConflict()` to the `script` sections of your code that use jQuery dependent functionalities - namely the `datepicker` and `validator`

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: -1,
        showButtonPanel: true
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: and there is a third one `jquery-latest.min.js` from CDN

Comment: `$.noConflict();` removes `$` alias and makes it undefined. No need for that

Comment: is there a specific jquery i should just have?

Comment: `jquery-latest.min.js` from the CDN should suffice.

Comment: When i removed all and just had the lastest jquery nothiing works